# react-native-maps LocalTile storage of tiles

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

With the new `LocalTile` feature of react-native-maps 0.19+, you can store tile images locally instead of using Apple or Google maps.

However, I haven't yet solved (because I can't find it in the docs and the source isn't giving me the clues I need) how to properly store and then address the local tiles.

I have my tiles generated and in the proper folder structure, and was hoping to place it alongside my other source files in, for example, `./data/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. But when using that or variations of that for my `pathTemplate` prop I just get the blank map. I'm assuming this is because MetroBundler or something else isn't trying to load up the `data/tiles` folder because I never `require` it as I would other resources.

Do I have to include the assets in the actual `ios` or `android` folders as a bundled asset of some sort? Or is there a way to include all the static resources in the project somehow to get them pulled over? Or am I just misunderstanding the `pathTemplate` property and file storage in general? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalTile` is intended to be used for locally stored tiles. That means tiles are stored locally, for example on external storage (sdcard) or in app's internal storage. `pathTemplate` will not work with assets or bundled files. It's working with real path inside android/ios system.

I wouldn't recommend you to store those tiles in assets, since it will increase significantly size of your application.

Best option is to store tiles (zipped) somewhere where you can download them within the app. If you really want to ship your app with those tiles, I'd recommend zip file in raw resources and extracting into app's internal storage (although I don't really know what is equivalent in iOS).